# socket closing early on multiple transfers

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send an object over the network to another computer (or the same computer) and then have said computer send an object back.

On the sending computer, I send the object and receive the returned object:

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        Object returnedObject;
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            returnedObject = (Object) ois.readObject();
        }
        return returnedObject;
```

On the receiving computer, I receive the object:

```
Object object;
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            object = (Object) ois.readObject();
        }
        return object;
```

and then send an object back:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
```

The error I get back is:

> SEVERE: null java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed   at
>   java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1137)    at

and it occurs while attempting to send an object back on the receiving computer.

The socket on the sending computer is using the same address and port as the socket on the receiving computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very small-scoped try-with-resources:

```
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
    returnedObject = (Object) ois.readObject();
}
```

This code is interpreted as:

- Get the input stream and build an `ObjectInputStream` around it.
- Read an object from the object stream
- **Close** the `ObjectInputStream`.

When you close the `ObjectInputStream` it automatically closes the `InputStream` that backs it, which is the socket's input stream. And the [documentation of `getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--) says:

> Closing the returned `InputStream` will close the associated socket.

You should make sure the try-with-resources has a bigger scope that covers the entire lifetime of the socket, or avoid using try-with-resources and make sure you close the `ObjecInputStream` properly when you are done with it or when there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it. Specifically, you closed the `ObjectInputStream` at the end of the try-with-resources block where it is declared. That closes the other stream of the socket and the socket itself.

Don't use new object streams per transfer. Use the same ones for the life of the socket, at both ends.